# KMM appLinkIntent on ios

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I'm currently learning kmm and cmp in particular and I'm redesigning the project to jetbrains compose from jetpack compose(android-only). Almost all the problems are solved except that I can't imagine how to accept incoming link on ios version as it is in android - via appLinkData. Also want to know how set link by default in ios version.

I tried already find needed thing in kotlin-lang doc for migration, but not found

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you need to look for iOS solution, it's possible to do from Xcode side.